# Asus rog laptop Wireless Adapter Crashing

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, crash, asus-laptop, wifi-driver

I have an [Asus ROG Strix G512LU](https://rog.asus.com/us/laptops/rog-strix/rog-strix-g15-series/spec) which is just 5 months old. And recently I am experiencing the problem that my WiFi adapter (Intel® ax201) is crashing frequently especially while **gaming**.
It crashes leading to loss of network connection and shows no available connection.

Furthermore, when I try to restart it, it doesn't work, but after like 10 to 15 mins of closing the game, it starts working again.

Please help me if you have any solution I will be thankful.
(P.S I am having this issue on fortnite , valorant and warzone)

Comment: If it's still under warranty you should contact them first and let them sort it out.

Comment: Its still under warranty, thanks for your suggestion but do you think its related to hardware damage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally, I had to get my wifi card replaced because there was no other option. My laptop was under warranty so it didn't cost me anything.